# Legacy dos system with flat file data store (ISAM-Files)

Tags: export, dos, legacy, isam

I have a legacy system which used to run on dos.  It is an ERP system for retail stores (fashion). It think it stores it's data in flat files.

I have files ending with *.KEY and other files ending with *.D00 (counting up).
I think the key files hold the key informationen and the D-Files hold some data ... there are alot D77 files...

As far as my investigation concerns this is not dfb or foxpro it could proprietary...

The company who wrote it is out of business of course so no chance for support or any hints. 
When I open these files in vim or other editors I get some binary signs and some text... I tryed it in hex mode but still nothing to use...
Is there any chance I can dump out the data... in csv, ascii, xml?

I am pretty sure that this is not a standard format. Can someone point me in a direction how those data were stored back in the days and how could I make them read-able...

Any tools, tips or tricks?

// EDIT

After some time I made some progress and can now post some details which I did not now of back then and made a good answer impossible.

I asume that the dos system was written in visual cobol and that the files could be b-tree files stored in ISAM format. I assume the closet thing I could provide is, that there is a possibility that the format is C-ISAM.

How can I access / view or modify these files... C#, JAVA, ruby.... everything new age language would be cool... I am not sure if I can handle cobol... It would be great to have a converter or a viewer tool preferable opensource...

Hope this clearifies more my question =)

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCOBOL](http://opencobol.org/) has a very active user group. The language itself is free and runs on Linux and Windows and perhaps MacOSX. Have a chat to the user group there; they may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

C-ISAM is for sure. Used in both COBOL and some other language's mainly in DOS.
It's already not developed anymore, probably due to the incursion of other developed database (Mysql and alike) that are more prevalent these days.

There is an open-source (not developed anymore) in https://sourceforge.net/projects/vbisam/ that provides some reverse compatibility.

If you could get access to the files in ISAM 4.0 (DOS), probably you would get the data and export it into another format (CSV i presume)

Answer (score -1):

Peachtree Accounting Software used those file extensions back in 1992.